# Renders properly in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari or IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, safari

Having issues with a) buttons in this code and b) the footer.

In Firefox/IE the buttons don't work properly and the footer shrinks and gets thrown in the corner.

The buttons shift to a different part of the page when pressed and the footer is unreadable.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

<head>
    <title>SAMPLE</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">

.con {text-align:center; }

button a {text-decoration:none; color:#08233e; }

#wtf_title {font-family: "Garamond"; font-weight: bold; font-size: 200%; padding-top:50px;}

#intro_text {font-family: "Helvetica", serif; color: black; padding-top:10px; font-style: italic;}

#reason {font-family: "Helvetica", serif; color: white; padding-top:50px; padding-bottom:50px;}

#credit {font-family: "helvetica"; font-size: 20%; color: black; text-align:center; }

button{
color:#08233e;
font:2.4em Futura, ‘Century Gothic’, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
font-size:70%;
padding:14px;
background:url(overlay.png) repeat-x center #ffcc00;
background-color:rgba(255,204,0,1);
border:1px solid #ffcc00;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
border-bottom:1px solid #9f9f9f;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
cursor:pointer;
}

button:hover{background-color:rgba(255,204,0,0.8);}

button:active{position:absolute;top:100px; left:50px}​

</style>

<body>

    <div class="con">
        <p id="wtf_title">SAMPLE</p>
        <hr noshade size=8 width="53%">
        <p id="intro_text">SAMPLE</p>
        <button><a href="WTFLBJ_Hate.html" class="button1">SAMPLE</a></button><br>
        <button><a href="WTFLBJ_Defend.html" class="button2">SAMPLE</a></button>            
    </div> 

    <div id="twitter-share-button"; style="position: absolute; top: 2px;" >
        <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.whatthefuckhaslebronjamesdone.com" data-text="Check this out:" data-count="none" data-hashtags="WTFLBJ">Tweet</a>
        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
    </div>

    <div id="fb_share"; style="position: absolute; top: 2px; left: 90px;" >
        <a name="fb_share"></a> 
            <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
         type="text/javascript">
            </script>   
    </div>


    <div id="credit"; style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px;  " >
        This site was created by <a href="http://www.twitter.com/varunsshetty">Varun Shetty</a> and <a href="http://www.twitter.com/bcfromblo">Bobby Corp</a>. Inspired by LBJ and <a href="http://www.whatthefuckhasobamadonesofar.com">WTF Obama</a>. 
    </div>
```

​

Comment: Your question is not clear but to start off with you haven't closed your <body> and <html> tag.

Comment: they are closed in the actual text; so that's not the issue. let me try and explain the problem more. the buttons, when clicked, physically shift to another part of the page in Firefox (they don't do that in chrome or safari). and the formatting of the footer is way off in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

In your style delete this line

button:active{position:absolute;top:100px; left:50px}

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/vCAgs/3/

I have checked only in chrome and internet explorer 9, but I think it works in all browsers

Comment: thank you - that did fix the issue of the buttons changing positions. in chrome, clicking the buttons takes me to a different page. but in firefox, clicking the button doesn't do anything. any way to fix that?